# Two modules not isomorphic if different number of elements?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Quick question:

With $R=\mathbb{Z}, M=\mathbb{Z}, P=2\mathbb{Z}, Q=3\mathbb{Z}$ modules, can I conclude that $M/P = \mathbb{Z}_2 \ncong M/Q = \mathbb{Z}_3$ because they have a different number of elements? Since modules are abelian groups?

Comment: yes that's true.

Comment: What do you mean by "modules are essentially abelian groups"?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes. So you could say "modules are abelian groups", and show that if two abelian groups are isomorphic then they are equipotent. I was confused by the word "*essentially*". What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A module homomorphism is by definition an isomorphism if it has an inverse that is a homomorphism. On the level of sets, any function with an inverse is a bijection, so isomorphic modules must have the same cardinality.

Note that this should hold for any reasonable algebraic object.

Comment: I wouldn't put it past the constructions of algebraic geometry. Surjective maps of sheaves that aren't surjective on sections are worrisome, for example.